# Insert a list of values into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

I'm trying to insert a list of values into a PostgreSQL data table.

I have this array called `rows` which displays something like this:

```
for row in rows:
       print(row)

(249607, 15802)
(249612, 15802)
(249613, 15802)
(249614, 15802)
(249615, 15802)
(249616, 15802)
(249617, 15802)
(249619, 15802)
(249620, 15802)
```

I'm trying to insert it into my table like this:

```
for row in rows:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO myTable (id1, id2, key, value) \
     VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)" , (row[0], row[1], "done", var3))
     conn.commit()
```

Unfortunately it just inserts 1 row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like the key value is a constant so you are only geting the last set of values

Comment: Which row is inserting of tuple? Very first or very last? Check constraints on table -any not null, primary/foreign/composite keys, etc. Might want to wrap with `try/catch` to output any exceptions.

Comment: Is possible that I had already key in table. There are some easy way to check if it exists to UPDATE, if not to INSERT ?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for the answer, I am using the new `psycopg2.extras.execute_batch()` method:

```
    mydict = map(lambda x : {'row0':x[0], 'row1':x[1], 'done':'done', 'var3':var3}, rows)
    query = """INSERT INTO myTable (id1, id2, key, value) \
               VALUES (%(row0)s, %(row1)s, %(done)s, %(var3)s)"""
    psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur, query, mydict)
```